# Minimal Magento2 installation a CMS framework

Tags: magento2, module, cms, composer, setup

Just want to setup Magento2 as a minimal CMS framework for an internal project, I am only interested in the following modules:

1. Backend
2. Authentication
3. ACL
4. ORM
5. API

I tried to define the magento modules in the composer.json but was not successful, seem most of the magento modules have dependencies defined with catalog module.... like the backend module etc

Can anyone suggest how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it should be possible to pick and choose the modules you want to use in your applications. However, as you already discovered, there are still many dependencies between most of the modules.

If you want to figure out a 'minimal' setup, I would suggest the following approach:

1. setup a complete project installation
2. disable the modules you don't want to use in the file `app/etc/config.php`
3. test the application and refine the settings in `config.php` when you come across dependency errors

When everything is working according to your needs, you can adjust `composer.json` to reflect your `config.php` file.

Comment: I was kind of thinking the same thing, just wanted to get an opinion from the community as well, thanks @Vicky